# After closing the lid, no screen display and computer hangs. Have to restart everytime.(14.10)

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, suspend, hibernate, lock

When I lock my laptop and close the lid, and again after sometime,when I open the lid, their is a blank screen with  no display and even if I press any key(s), my system does not wake up.I have to Restart computer every time through main power button of laptop. This Problem started when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10.

Please Help !

Comment: To debug this and found out if it is only the screen that stays blank or if it is the laptop that is down, I suggest that you install a ssh server with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and configure it so that you are able to log in via ssh into your laptop. So when the computer hangs again, try to ssh into the laptop, and if you can, then it is only a problem with the screen.

Comment: Is this problem related to Hibernation ? I saw some similar problems, and not clearly, but answer was hibernate. But didn't got any solution. :/

Comment: @Cristaino7Stark Did you tried `sudo pm-hibernate` whether your system goes in to hibernation properly.

Comment: @Cristaino7Stark: This is a forwarded comment from the user _Vencen_ who gave this as an answer: **please give the laptops model number.**